# How can I go from Morocco to Mali by car?

Tags: road-trips, morocco, mali

How can I go from Morocco to Mali by car? I can't cross the border with Algeria because there aren't. So what can I do?

Comment: The only halfway realistic option seems to be to go along the coast across Mauritania and then enter Mali from Senegal (that border is open) but even that is discouraged by every source I could find.

Answer (score 4):

At a basic level, you would either [travel down the coast of Western Sahara and then cut in through Mauritania](http://goo.gl/maps/xAKxb), do the same but [through Senegal instead of Mauritania](http://goo.gl/maps/9fIS2), or [catch a ferry from Morocco to Spain, back to Algeria and then come down from the north (somewhat of a crazy detour)](http://goo.gl/maps/tJqRn)

However the travel advisories indicate that the areas to avoid are [north Mali](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/mali/safety-and-security) (ok, the first two options do so) and [northern Mauritania](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/mauritania), which currently has an advisory for no travel at all.  This is obviously a problem as both the first two options (the preferable ones) proceed through this area.

[image]

First-hand reports tend to indicate actual travel through the area is ok, as long as it's at day only and you stay at population centres.  There doesn't seem to currently be negative reports on the Mauritania-Mali border after the ceasation of the French push through northern Mali, nor are these borders listed as currently closed, but proceeding through Senegal is probably the safer option anyway.

As Annoyed mentioned in the comments, Mauritania has shut a lot of border crossings currently (2014) due to Ebola.  That includes all crossings into Mali, but also all into Senegal other than those at Rosso and Diama.  The second route through Senegal is still potentially open because it crosses the border at Rosso.

Comment: (+1) Note that according to the French Ministry of Foreign Affairs, the whole east of Mauritania is a military zone that require a special authorization to travel and “[L’accès au Mali par la route depuis la Mauritanie doit se faire exclusivement par le territoire sénégalais.](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/conseils-aux-voyageurs/conseils-par-pays/mauritanie-12291/)” The last kidnapping reported in this area was in 2012, not so long ago. The border with Mali is also apparently closed for unrelated reasons (Ebola).

Comment: Thanks for the note on ebola, it's worth adding.  I was only searching for unrest-related closings.

Comment: if we start including boats, why not put the car on a freighter from Morocco to Senegal, bypassing Mauretania (and western Sahara, which afaik is suffering from a civil war still) completely? Probably your safest option (and that's relative when traveling in that part of the world).